# 1px page overflow on chrome but not firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, overflow

I have a rather frustrating issue that is causes my web app to appear rather glitch. The idea of my design is that it is super responsive and that the page/document doesn't scroll, but the elements with in the page do. As a result I have 100% height on a alot of divs. For some reason I have no idea why, chrome has decided that 100% is actually = to 100% + 1px, however firefox has no issues. This 1 px causes an ugly scroll bar to appear on the right side and causes the page to jump up and down when you scroll the containing elements. So I thought, great lets just calc(100% -1px) and see how it goes. Well it fixes the scroll bar, but now we have 1px gap at the bottom. Seems like I can't win. It's either 1px to much or 1px not enough...
Any way things I have tried:

- Remove all lineheights
- Calc 1px as mentioned above (.page-container)
- Removed all bootstrap glyphicons from page
- Disabled bootstrap tooltips

Note: I Notice on chrome, if I clear the cache and hard reset there is a delay of about 500ms before the scroll bar appears, but I think that may be because my divs css animate to 100%?

Here are the links to my css files and a screen shot of the issue in chrome and working in Firefox.

[css-file-1](http://www.mycs.net.au/stack/bootstrap-important.css)

[css-file-2](http://www.mycs.net.au/stack/invoices.css)

[css-file-3](http://www.mycs.net.au/stack/view-standard-layout.css)

[image]
[image]

I am happy to upload the entire site to my server if needed. Message me for private link. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that "textAngular" which is a html editor that integrates with our angular SPA was placing a 1px high input at the bottom of the page with an ID of: textAngular-editableFix-010203040506070809. I simply set its height to 0px and walla problem solved. Thanks for your help anyway. Hopefully this can help anyone else that might come across this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

box-sizing: border-box;

on all the items that you want to have a height of 100%. If that doesn't work, try to find out which element takes longest to load after you clear the cache and reload the page and find out if there's something wrong with that element.

Comment: Regarding part two of your answer, is there a way to view the loading times of elements with the chrome inspect element? What is the best way of achieving what you have suggested? I will take a look at the box-sizing:border-box when I get back to the office. I have since noticed that Firefox seems to be the anomaly as iPad and android tablets both show the 1px bottom as well!

Comment: Check the "Network" tab in the Chrome inspector. It should show you the loading times of all assets. Did the box-sizing fix it?